# How to compare and extract the recent date from an array of dates in Perl

Tags: perl, date, time, compare

I have written a Perl script to extract contents from log file, in the process I have an array containing dates that are previously extracted using regex

```
2014-03-05 18:22:06
2014-03-06 10:05:56
2014-04-29 16:04:30
2014-04-29 17:22:13
2014-05-02 10:35:02
2014-05-07 18:09:23
```

Now I need to compare all the above to find the recent date so that I can again use a regex to extract the whole line containing the recent date from a log file

Update:

```
my @dates = $1 if (/^(.*)\|Info\|(.*) port (.*)/);
my ($min) = sort @dates;
my ($max) = reverse sort @dates;
print "Max = $max\nMin = $min\n"
```

Output for the code suggested by both @Miller and @choroba

```
Max = 2014-04-09 13:55:50
Min = 2014-04-09 13:55:50
Max = 2014-05-07 18:09:23
Min = 2014-05-07 18:09:23
```

The output I actually need

```
Recent Start Time: 2014-05-07 18:09:23
```

Answer (score 3):

For dates in this format, you can use plain string comparison (`cmp`, `lt`, `gt` etc).

```
my ($min, $max) = @dates;
for (@dates) {
    $min = $_ if $min gt $_;
    $max = $_ if $max lt $_;
}
```

Comment: I get the error `Use of uninitialized value $max in string lt`
please find the code update 

    `my @dates = $1 if (/^(.*)\|Info\|(.*) port (.*)/);  
    my ($min, $max) = @dates;  
    for (@dates)  
    {  
    $min = $_ if $min gt $_;  
    $max = $_ if $max lt $_;  
    }  
    print "$min \n $max";`

Comment: @AbilashA: That isn't right. The array `@dates` is supposed to be the *"array containing dates that are previously extracted using regex"*, you will get `Use of uninitialized value` only if that array contains less than two dates, in which case the problem is trivial. In any case your code will define only `$min`, and `$max` will still be undefined.

Comment: @Borodin, Could you please help me to make the array contain all the dates? would it be possible to assign one array value to another?

Comment: @AbilashA: Yes I could, but I have no idea what you data looks like. Is it in a file? And as for *"would it be possible to assign one array value to another?"* yes, of course it would, but I don't see how that relates to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `@dates` array isn't enormous, in which case `sort` would be an indulgence, you can write just

```
my ($min, $max) = (sort @dates)[0,-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) your dates as your data happens to be in an easily ordered format.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @dates = split /\n/, do {local $/; <DATA>};

my ($min, $max) = (sort @dates)[0, -1];

print "Max = '$max'\nMin = '$min'\n";;

__DATA__
2014-03-05 18:22:06
2014-03-06 10:05:56
2014-04-29 16:04:30
2014-04-29 17:22:13
2014-05-02 10:35:02
2014-05-07 18:09:23
```

Outputs:

```
Max = '2014-05-07 18:09:23'
Min = '2014-03-05 18:22:06'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, actually I am not going to write the dates into a file and them read from it, instead I get all the data into an array

Comment: Why not just `chomp(my @dates = <DATA>)`, and then `my ($min, $max) = (sort @data)[0,-1]`?

Comment: @Miller, I tried skipping the line, but the comparison doesn't apply for the whole array, instead it applies to each of the array elements, therefore printing each value twice (Max and Min), could you please point out where am I making the mistake, I have updated my part of script in the question

Comment: @AbilashA Your line `my @dates = $1 if (/^(.*)\|Info\|(.*) port (.*)/);` is only assigning a single value to your `@dates` array.  Do you see the problem in that?

Comment: @Miller, Yes, you are right, but how could I solve this problem, is there any way to assign the entire result to the array and them process further?